# anulando ação de função caso resultado seja falso

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho a seguinte função: se o dado digitado for NaN, ele dá foco no campo e altera a borda

```js
function validaNumero(){
 dado = document.getElementById("new_partner");
 var formulario = document.getElementById("new_partner");
 var dado = formulario.partner_registry_number.value;
  if(isNaN(dado)) {
   formulario.partner_registry_number.style.focus;
   formulario.partner_registry_number.style.border = "2px solid red";
   return false;
  } 
 }
```

Até aí, tudo bem, mas depois da primeira fez que a função é acessada, a barra sempre fica vermelha, mesmo digitando um dado válido. Como resolver isto?

Comment: Podes colocar o HTML?

Comment: Acredito que vai ter chamar a função novamente em algum determinado momento (onchange, submit) e caso seja válido voltar a borda ao normal.

Comment: Clica em [edit] e junta o HTML para podermos responder à tua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Toda vez que o código for executado e o valor for NaN, ele irá alterar a borda para vermelho. Depois que o valor não for mais NaN, é preciso fazer com que a borda volte ao estado original.

Você só precisa de um `else`.

```
if(isNaN(dado)) {
    formulario.partner_registry_number.style.border = "2px solid red";
} else {
    formulario.partner_registry_number.style.border = ""; // borda original
}
```

Ou para optimizar o código..

```
formulario.partner_registry_number.style.border = isNaN(dado) ? '2px solid red' : '';
```

Comment: `formulario.partner_registry_number.style.border = isNaN(dado) ? "2px solid red" : "";` para ficar numa só linha. `+1`

Comment: coloquei na resposta, @Sergio.